# Finding a matrix $A$ that always has one or infinite solutions to $Ax=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm told I should be able to find a $m\times n$ matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ that satisfies

\begin{align}
r=m < n &&\boldsymbol{A}x=b \text{ has 1 or $\infty$ solutions}
\end{align}

Take for example

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

We have $r=2;\ m=2;\ n=3$ but this always has exactly one solution.

If we consider two dependent rows, then there are infinite solutions when there is a solution but also no solutions for some vectors $b$.

How can a make a matrix that will always have one or infinite solutions?

Comment: Why do you think that "this always has exactly one solution"? For your matrix, we always have infinitely many solutions

Comment: That said, it is impossible to have a matrix $A$ and vectors $b_1,b_2$ such that $Ax = b_1$ has exactly one solution and $Ax = b_2$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yeah you’re right. Sooo I guess I’m not sure what they’re looking for.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, is there a way to make a matrix that satisfies those requirements only has one solution to B? It looks like it always has infinite solutions

Comment: For $m<n$, it is an underdetermined system which either has no solution or infinitely many solutions. If the matrix $A$ is of rank $m$, then $Ax=b$ will have infinitely many solutions. If the matrix $A$ is rank deficient, only then it may happen that $Ax=b$ has no solution.

Comment: You don't have a unique solution because you have more variables $x_i$'s than the equations. So you can always fix $n-m$ variables arbitrarily and solve for the other $m$ variables.

Comment: @unobservable_node yeah, that's what I thought too. I brought up the concern with my professor today during class. He confirmed that the problem is incorrect. Thanks!